# How to utilize Google Maps from PC to mobile device?

Tags: google-maps

I want to use the destination that I search for in Google maps on a computer, and send that to a mobile device. How is this done? Is a functionality that is part of Google maps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to just share a link.

There are great instructions for this available here: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361

> **Share the map**
>
> Whether you’ve found a cool spot or have helpful directions, you can
>   share your map with others over email, Google+, Facebook, Twitter, or
>   text.
>
> 1. Open Google Maps.
> 2. Make a map or get directions.
> 3. When you're ready to share, click the main menu [image: main menu].
> 4. Select Share or embed map.
>
>    - If you don't see Share or embed map, click Link to this map instead.
> 5. Optional: Check the box next to "Short URL" to create a shorter
>      link.
> 6. Double-click the link to highlight it, then copy it by pressing
>      CTRL+C (for PC) or ⌘+C (for Mac).
> 7. Paste the link by pressing CTRL+V (for PC) or ⌘+V (for Mac) wherever
>      you want to share the map, like an email or Google+ post.

I have noticed that the icon for the menu has changed - it's now a gear [image: gear icon] and is located in the bottom-right corner of the map.

You can send that link to your device by email, IM, whatever suits you.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From : [Send directions to your phone, car, or tablet](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6081481?hl=en)

- Step 1: Add your device or car
- Step 2: Send a place